# Fields only echoed when value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

To avoid open rows on the screen, how can I reach that the 5 vip fields, only are echoed when there is a value in it?

Thanks, Benny

```
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbase');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "
    SELECT
        user.FName, 
        user.LName, 
        user.HerbalifeID, 
        user.UplineS,
        registratie.PartnerFName as pfn, 
        registratie.PartnerLName as pln, 
        registratie.NaamVIP1 as vip1, 
        registratie.NaamVIP2 as vip2, 
        rgistratie.NaamVIP3 as vip3, 
        registratie.NaamVIP4 as vip4, 
        registratie.NaamVIP5 as vip5 
    FROM
        registratie 

    INNER JOIN user 
        ON registratie.userID = user.UserID 
        AND registratie.eventID =127;
";
$result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error.__LINE__);

if ($result->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->FName} {$row->LName} {$row->HerbalifeID} {$row->pfn} {$row->pln}<br>
        {$row->vip1}{$row->vip2}{$row->vip3}{$row->vip4}{$row->vip5})<br><br>"; //only
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Results';
}
```

Comment: have you tried isset() function yet? You can also use tertiary operator ? :

Comment: `isset` will match an empty value, use `!empty()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty({$row->vip1}) and !empty({$row->vip2}) and !empty({$row->vip3}) and !empty({$row->vip4}) and !empty({$row->vip5}) ){
    echo "{$row->FName} {$row->LName} {$row->HerbalifeID} {$row->pfn} {$row->pln}<br>{$row->vip1}{$row->vip2}{$row->vip3}{$row->vip4}{$row->vip5})<br><br>";
}else{
    echo "{$row->FName} {$row->LName} {$row->HerbalifeID} {$row->pfn} {$row->pln})<br><br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it. 
If you want to print only when all vips are filled, use the following code:

```
//...
$range = range(1,5);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

    //This will be printed in every iteration
    echo "{$row->FName} {$row->LName} {$row->HerbalifeID} {$row->pfn} {$row->pln}";

    //if one of the vips has no value, go to the next $row
    foreach($range as $r){
        $vipColumn = "vip$r";
        if(empty($row->$vipColumn)){
            continue 2; //breaks both 'foreach' and 'while' loops 
        }
    }

    //This only echo when all vips has values
    echo "<br>{$row->vip1}{$row->vip2}{$row->vip3}{$row->vip4}{$row->vip5})<br><br>";

}
//...
```

Comment: Sorry Carlos, I mean it should echo only there where a value is in it, 
So it can be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 vips.

Comment: So, I think it will do the job

Comment: I have changed to >>>  continue 1;